# Using powershell, [Get-ChildItem] I want to search recursively for all exe by the Name display the highest FileVersion and FullName

Tags: powershell, recursion, versioning

Using powershell,
Like [Get-ChildItem]

I want to search recursively for all exe by the '.Name' display the highest '.FileVersion' and '.FullName'

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse \\server\loads\*\Product\*.exe | sort Name,FileVersion | Select-Object -Property  FileVersion, Name, FullName | Out-GridView
```

the 1st * is Alpha , Beta, Release and the 2nd * is a sub-product [possible 2 depth] and the the executable

how ever this LOADS share has gotten unruly and as may backups and recursive storing of EXEs

I am Looking for an output like:

```
FileVersion Name                         FullName
----------- ----                         --------
1.0.0.3     PBX.exe         \\server\loads\Beta\product\Platform\PBXInstall\PBXInterface.exe
2.0.0.0     Door.exe         \\server\loads\Release\product\Platform\DoorInstall\DoorInterface.exe
1.0.1.3     CA.exe         \\server\loads\Alpha\product\Platform\CAInstall\CAInterface.exe
1.0.9.3     POS.exe         \\server\loads\Release\product\Platform\POSInstall\POSInterface.exe
```

Each of these has a count in all 3 folders and possible more in the low depths as it was stored incorrectly

I need to get Just the newest no matter the release cycle

Comment: `FileVersion` is not a default member.  Where is it defined?

Comment: [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("somefilepath").FileVersion

Comment: Update-TypeData -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo -MemberName FileVersion -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value {
   [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($this.FullName) | % {
      [Version](($_.FileMajorPart, $_.FileMinorPart, $_.FileBuildPart, $_.FilePrivatePart)-join".") 
   }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to search for all exe files in a path, then for each exe name  eg PBX.exe you want to show the path to only the highest version.

Here is the solution I devised on Windows 10

```
GCI -recurse *.exe | Select -first 20| select name,fullname,@{l='FileVersion';e={[SYSTEM.version]($_.versioninfo.fileversion)}} | group Name | %{$_.Group | sort -descending fileVersion | select -first 1}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path '\\server\loads\*\Product\*.exe' |
  Select-Object -Property @(
      'Name','FullName',
      @{ N='FileVersion';
         E={[Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.FullName) |
              ForEach-Object {
                  [Version](($_.FileMajorPart, $_.FileMinorPart, $_.FileBuildPart, $_.FilePrivatePart) -join '.' }
           }
       }
  ) |
  Sort-Object -Property 'Name','FileVersion' |
  Out-GridView
```

Comment: This is almost the original code I used, not doing anything I hadn't already done